# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{f_n}$ where $f_n$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

Can we show convergence of$$B=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n}{f_n}$$where $f_n$ is the $n$'th Fibonacci number?

And then can we determine the exact value of $B$?

Comment: It may be useful to know, for this or similar problems, that $f_n$ grows exponentially for large $n$, particularly $f_n\sim\phi^n$ where $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can conclude it based on [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) i.e. if $a(n)$ is an eventually monotone decreasing sequence, converging to $0$, then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n a(n)$$ converges.

In your case, $a(n) = \dfrac{n}{f_n}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence for some $n>m$, converging to $0$, since $f_n$ grows exponentially.

Hence, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\dfrac{n}{f_n}$$ converges.

---

**EDIT** Mathematica gives the sum of the infinite series as $\approx 0.2692050394$ and the [inverse symbolic calculator](http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=0.2692050394&lookup_type=simple) seems to suggest this number is not related to any of the other "well-known constants".

Comment: I have a question. Could I apply the same solution replacing $f_n$ with $p_n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$'th prime?

Comment: Marvis, $p_n$ is roughly $n\log n$.

Comment: Also, $n/f_n$ is not monotone decreasing, not if you take $f_1=f_2=1$ as is commonly done.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oops what a blunder I made! Thanks for pointing it out! Have removed it.

Comment: Finally, isn't the ordinary everyday alternating series test good enough for the original question (after you clear out the non-decreasing part)?

Comment: @sunny As Gerry points out, $p_n \sim n \log n$ and hence $\dfrac{n}{p_n} \sim \dfrac1{\log n}$ which is a monotone decreasing sequence to $0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. But I have Dirichlet test, already written up on my computer and hence I find it easy to copy paste it.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. I have added that it is a monotone decreasing sequence for $n>m$. Thanks.

Comment: @Marvis Is there etiquette about changing the question slightly? I also want to ask what the series converges to, but I'm not sure if it's polite to add it in now.

Comment: @sunny Sure. Feel free to change it. I don't think it is an issue.

Comment: I think it is very bad etiquette to ask a question, get a good and sufficient answer, and then change the question. You should 1. accept Marvis' answer, if it suits you, and then post the other question as a new question, and 2. think a question through next time, before you post it.

Comment: Can I expect to find the value of convergence by paper, or would that be unlikely?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I apologize. I wasn't thinking the question through when asking it, because I thought the answer was that the series didn't converge.